# R / R Studio unable to load workspace/project

Tags: r, memory-management, out-of-memory, rstudio

I have been working with large objects and have received an error when trying to load my project in RStudio (or similarly, my workspace in the R console). I know it is a space issue. I can see from my task manager that the memory and disk are being maxxed out. The CPU is maxing out for a single core. I know I need to remove some objects and make some matrices sparse to free up space,

My specific questions are:

1. Can I modify or remove objects when I do not have the project/workspace loaded?
2. Can I set the memory to be higher using something like `memory.limit` for a project load?
3. Can I use more than one core of my processor for the project load?
4. Any other ideas?

Here are the errors:

> WARNING: Failed to restore workspace from '~/D/. . .' Reason: cannot
>   allocate vector of size 148 Kb

Here is the session info for Rstudio:

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>       Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

And I also tried it in R; the resultant error is:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 148 Kb

Here is the session info for the R console:

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

What I have done so far:

1. Updated Rstudio to latest version 1.0.44
2. Updated R to 3.3.2
3. `gc()` (both in R console and in Rstudio)
4. Restarted programs and computer
5. Tried to use `remove()` without being in the project

UPDATE: I was able to find a work around so that I could view my objects.

1. I opened R. It pulled up the scripts from the previously opened project, and displayed the above error, leaving the environment box blank (no objects).
2. I ran `memory.limit(size = 50000)`.
3. In the environment box of RStudio, I selected the open file icon, and chose my latest saved R workspace associated with this project, and it very slowly loaded the objects.
4. I exported some objects, deleted some.

The project is still large and I am afraid to work in it, lest I not be able to open it up again. Still looking for answers.

Comment: Try opening your `.Rproj` file in a text editor (NOT RStudio!) and edit/add the following: `RestoreWorkspace: No`

Comment: @Phil Are you suggesting I open Rstudio without my workspace restored? Will I be able to see my objects from my project without the workspace restored? I do need to access my objects that are in my project.

Comment: Yes, to allow you to get the project open. You should be able to reproduce the objects you need once you've got the project open. The only other alternative is to install more RAM

Comment: @Phil, I already can get the project to open, the error seems to just relate to restoring the objects.

Comment: "[I] have received an error when trying to load my project in RStudio"?

Comment: I assumed successful loading of the project included showing any open source code and restoring the objects. Is this wrong (should I edit my question?).  My .R code files are loaded but my objects, some of which take hours to create (graphs) are now gone. (environment is empty). Hand wringing.

Comment: Why don't you `save` your objects?